# I got points for an accepted answer and vote up, but the question was closed

Tags: support

I've been pretty active on Stackoverflow today, but I'm a little confused now.

I saw that I'd been awarded points and a vote up for an answer I posted on a question. I notice the question has been closed.

I can't see any way to tell if the question was closed before or after my points were awarded, but I'd just like to know, can I get points after a question is closed? Should this be allowed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, you can. Closing is a temporary state, in which the question can be improved. It's perfectly fine if people vote for it or if you accept an answer.

Deletion vanishes all the rep tied to it (unless it has a net score >3 and has been around for more than 60 days)

So, be happy with the rep you got--it's legitimate :)

Comment: The requirements being a score of at least 3 and having been visible for at least 60 days.

Comment: @DanielFischer thiught it was that, but wasn't sure--thansk for confirming :)